# Scroll whole fragment with fragments inside

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, scroll

I have a fragment called SearchFragment which contains 3 FrameLayouts inside. Fragments are loading at runtime to these FrameLayouts. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_search__song_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".ui.fragments.search.SearchFragment"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_search__artist_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/fragment_search__song_container"
        tools:context=".ui.fragments.search.SearchFragment" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_search__album_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/fragment_search__artist_container"
        tools:context=".ui.fragments.search.SearchFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: SearchFragment]

So, I need to scroll this whole SearchFragment down (to see the third "more" button).

I tried to add ScrollView and NestedScrollView and place layout with these FrameLayouts inside of it, but it only results in scrolling each fragment separately, which is not what I need

Comment: Sounds like this should just be a RecyclerView with multiple ViewTypes, and no fragments involved at all. See https://github.com/lisawray/groupie for a simple implementation of RecyclerView with multiple item view types.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I use fragments for reusability. Can this library help with that?
Anyway I don't have enough time to refactor it all, I use fragment everywhere. But still thanks

Comment: Well then good luck. This is not what Fragments were designed for, although maybe you can hack ViewPager2 to work with it.